# login error when I try to login the user. Django

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

Good evening community,

I am building my first website and I am facing the following two problems when I try to logging the user:

1. I can see the password as I write it.
2. When I click submit I get a 404 because it sends me to the wrong URL: Request URL:   http://127.0.0.1:8000/login_user/simple_investing/create_company.htm/

Here is my code:

Forms.py:

```
class UserForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2')


class UserLogin(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields= ('username', 'password')
```

Views.py:

```
def login_page(request):
    messages.success(request, 'Account created successfully')
    form = UserLogin
    if request.method == 'POST':       
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)             
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('simple_investing/create_company.htm/')
        
    context = {'form' : form}
    return render(request, 'simple_investing/login.htm', context)
```

HTHML:

```
{% for message in messages %}
    <p>{{ message }}</p>
{% endfor %}
    <p>Log in and start using our tools!</p>
<form action= "" method='post'>
   {% csrf_token %}

{% for field in form %}
    <p>{{field.label}}{{field}}</p>       
{% endfor %}

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Login User</button> 
 </form>
```

Any hints?

Comment: Why don't you try `Django's inbuilt login function` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Lars said you can use Django's built in login function:
[Django auth system](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/default/)

But, after that, you can still choose where to redirect after login with

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/profiles/home'
```

In you settings.py